# Puppeteer - Cannot Pull Correct CSS Selector in Hotel Website

Tags: css, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Goal:** Save all the names of hotels in a .txt file (after clicking through the inputs in website).

**Issue:** I believe my CSS selector (`'[class^="js-hotel-location"] > [class^="js-hotel-name"] > span.l-property-name'`) may be incorrect because my `candidates` function returns an empty array, furthermore, without `if(!nameEl) return false;` line, I get a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')`.

**Expected output for `candidates_distance.txt`:** ["Aloft Chicago Downtown River North", "The Gwen, a Luxury Collection Hotel, Michigan Avenue Chicago", "Sheraton Grand Chicago Riverwalk"]

**Actual output:** []

[image]

**Code causing Issue:** `candidates` function that returns an empty array:

```
    // ! STUCK: candidates function returning empty array - likely CSS selector is incorrect 
    const candidates = await page.$$eval('[class^="js-hotel-location"] > [class^="js-hotel-name"] > span.l-property-name', elements => {
        return elements
          .filter(el => {
            const nameEl = el.querySelector('[class^="js-hotel-location"] > [class^="js-hotel-name"] > span.l-property-name');
            if(!nameEl) return false;
            const name = nameEl.textContent.trim();
            return name !== "";
          })
          .map(el => el.textContent.trim());
    });
    fs.writeFile('candidates_name.txt', JSON.stringify(candidates), function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
```

---

**Code to Reproduce:**

`constants.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    URL: "https://www.marriott.com/default.mi",
    DESTINATION: "Chicago, IL, USA",
    START_MONTH: "August",
    START_DAY: 7,
    END_MONTH: "August",
    END_DAY: 10,
    PROMO_CODE: "MMP"
}
```

`index.js`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const constants = require('./marriot_constants.js');
const blockResources = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-block-resources');
const fs = require('fs/promises');

// ! NOT WORKING: Configure the plugin to block all images and stylesheets
const pluginConfig = blockResources({
    blockedTypes: new Set(['image', 'stylesheet'])
});
puppeteer.use(pluginConfig);

let browser;
(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
    await page.setUserAgent(ua);
    await page.setViewport({width: 800, height: 10700});
    await page.goto(constants.URL, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

    await page.type('[id$="-search-destination"]', constants.DESTINATION);

    await page.click(".search__calendar-value");
    await page.waitForSelector(".search-dates-popup");

    const findMonth = async targetMonth => {
        for(let i = 0; i < 12; i++){ 
            const month = await page.$eval(".DayPicker-Month", el => el.textContent);
            if(month.includes(targetMonth)) break;
            await page.click('[aria-label="Next Month"]');
        }   
    };

    const chooseDay = day => page.$$eval(".DayPicker-Day-value", (els, day) =>
        els.find(e => e.textContent.trim() === day).click(), String(day)
    );

    await findMonth(constants.START_MONTH);
    await chooseDay(constants.START_DAY);
    await findMonth(constants.END_MONTH);
    await chooseDay(constants.END_DAY);
    await page.click('button.m-button-secondary');

    await page.click('[class^="StyledSpecialRatesDiv"] > [class="t-font-s"]');
    await page.waitForSelector('[class^="StyledPopupMain"]');
    await page.click('[class^="StyledRadioButtonDiv"]:nth-child(5)')
    await page.type('[class^="StyledRadioButtonDiv"]:nth-child(5)', constants.PROMO_CODE);
    await page.waitForSelector('[class="crop-promo-code"] > [class="m-button-secondary m-button-s"]');
    await page.click('[class="crop-promo-code"] > [class="m-button-secondary m-button-s"]');

    await page.click('[id$="find-a-hotel-homePage-form"] > [class^="StyledFindBtn"]');
    await page.waitForNavigation();

    // ! STUCK: candidates function returning null array or cannot pull Hotel Names - likely CSS selector is incorrect 
    const candidates = await page.$$eval('[class^="js-hotel-location"] > [class^="js-hotel-name"] > span.l-property-name', elements => {
        return elements
          .filter(el => {
            const nameEl = el.querySelector('[class^="js-hotel-location"] > [class^="js-hotel-name"] > span.l-property-name');
            if(!nameEl) return false;
            const name = nameEl.textContent.trim();
            return name !== "";
          })
          .map(el => el.textContent.trim());
    });
    fs.writeFile('candidates_name.txt', JSON.stringify(candidates), function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
      
})()
.catch(err => console.error(err))
.finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test out selectors in your browser console, writing it in the following format and running it. It will show what your selector selects.

```
$$('span.l-property-name');
```

In your case, `[class^="js-hotel-name"]` isn't directly under `[class^="js-hotel-location"]` so it selects nothing.

should be

```js
[class^="js-hotel-location"] [class^="js-hotel-name"] > span.l-property-name
```

but that can also select additional `vacation home` offers, so  your tag should be

```js
[id^="property-record-map"] span.l-property-name
```

You also don't need the filter part in your code :

```js
const candidates = await page.$$eval('[id^="property-record-map"] span.l-property-name', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim()));
```

For what is in your `constants.js` file, the selector returns more hotels than you've written, and the only way I get the output

```js
["Aloft Chicago Downtown River North", "The Gwen, a Luxury Collection Hotel, Michigan Avenue Chicago", "Sheraton Grand Chicago Riverwalk"]
```

is if I do  additional steps below which filters by brands *(The Luxury Collection, Sheraton, Aloft)* and by price *(200+ USD)* :

```js
// add after -> await page.waitForNavigation();

async function waitClick(selector) {
    let btn = await page.waitForSelector(selector);
    await btn.click();
}

await waitClick('[data-component-name="searchFilters"] a.m-button'); // All Filters
await waitClick('a[data-code=Brands]'); // filters > brands btn


let selectBrands = ['a[data-for=brands_LC]','a[data-for=brands_SI]','a[data-for=brands_AL]']; // Brands to select
for (let s of selectBrands) {
    await waitClick(s); 
    await page.waitForSelector('div.js-sort-and-filter-form',{visible : true}); // wait for selector
}

await waitClick('a[data-code=price]'); // filters > price btn
await waitClick('label[for=price_3]'); // 200+ USD

await page.waitForSelector('div.js-sort-and-filter-form',{visible : true});

await waitClick('form.js-submit-form button[type=Submit]'); // Apply filters

await page.waitForSelector('body');  

const candidates = await page.$$eval('[id^="property-record-map"] span.l-property-name', elements => elements.map(el => el.textContent.trim()));

// next comes the fs.writeFile part
```